# Using Google Fonts with only CSS access?

Tags: website-design, fonts, css, web-fonts, html

In the free version of Cargo Collective, I'm able to edit the complete CSS, but not the HTML of my site. Assuming I stick to the free version and thus remain able to only edit/add to the CSS, is there a way for me to use a Google Font in one of my divs?

I've only found ways to use Google Fonts that require access to the HTML.

Comment: This question belongs on http://stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) and you select any font, under "Embed" it gives you two ways of importing it: "Standard" (which loads it in the HTML via a `<link />` tag), and "@import". You want to use "[@import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import)".

[image]

You can see that you can include fonts via CSS by using

```
@import 'https://fonts.google.com?css?family=Font+Name';
```

**Make sure and put this in the top of your CSS file**.

Once this is done, you can use it like you would any other font:

```
.someSelector {
    font-family: 'Font Name', fallback-font; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import fonts in CSS like this:

```
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=FontName';
```

Comment: that does require access to the HTML

Comment: @Luciano No, it doesn't (granted the developer does indeed have access to the CSS)